# Connecting traces to a top-to-bottom layer via on a four layer PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I want all vias on my 4-layer PCB to start on top and stop on bottom layer and I want to be able to connect the traces from inner power and GND layers to the vias too. But it just doesn't happen!

The layers of the traces that I can pull out of the via is either top or bottom:

[image: via properties]

Even when the trace layer is manually changed out of a via, it seems like they are not connected.

The connection lines still stay (there is no connection).

Here's an example:

[image: two vias]

What setting do I need to change so that I can have traces from inner layers connected to vias too?

Comment: Are we to assume you are using Altium? You might want to add this information to your question, along with the version.

Comment: You might need to define a 4-layer via pad-stack, or at least find out how to switch on the one you already have somewhere.

Comment: Maybe the net-line connection is remaining because there are other unrouted 5 volt nodes that are beyond the extents of your picture?

Comment: Are you using polygons or planes on inner layers?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes Tim, I am using planes.. So this is a reason why I can't rout anything in the power plane using vias?

Comment: You need to select the plane region and assign it a net, then it will connect. Planes are kind of archaic and you may find it better to use polygon(s) on a signal layer.

Comment: The fact that your trace is green says to me that you are drawing traces on a mechanical layer, not a copper layer.